# POST method giving errors in Netbeans/ REST

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to build a POST method in netbeans/ java using REST. For some reason this code keeps returning an error when invoked, any ideas?

```
@POST
@Path("findByImage")
public String findByImage() {
    return "hello";
}
```

It returns the error:

Type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type ', application/xml'
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 logs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you send POST request with wrong ‘Content-Type’ header (‘, application/xml’). For example I can reproduce it with next command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: , application/xml" http://localhost:8080/jsfDemo/resources/testing/findByImage
```